# Is it possible to return a reference via an argument passed by reference?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

I want to return a boolean or success/failure enum from the function and modify an argument by reference. However, I want to construct a reference in the calling function instead of copying the value.

I have some container (say 'example_q' of type std::queue). queue.front() will return a reference to the value stored in the queue. I can make a copy of that reference (example A) or I can take a reference of that reference (example B), allowing the value to stay in the queue but be utilized outside of it.

A)

```
int a = example_q.front();
```

B)

```
int& b = example_q.front();
```

Using this difference I could also return the queued value:

A)

```
int get_front()
{
    int a = example_q.front(); 
    return a;
}
```

B)

```
int& get_front()
{
    return example_q.front();
}
```

Using option 'B' I can avoid unnecessary copies without moving the data out of the queue via std::move() semantics.

My question is, can I do 'B' via an argument passed by reference? Would I need to use std::move()/rvalues/&& somehow?

```
void get_front(int& int_ref)
{
    // somehow don't copy the value into referenced int_ref, but construct 
    // a reference in the caller based on an input argument?
    int_ref = example_q.front(); 
}
```

The problem this would solve is making API match other functions that modify reference arguments but return a success/failure value, ie:

```
if(q.get_front(referrence_magic_here))
{
    ...
}
```

I could reverse the order to get the desired result, IE:

```
int& get_front(bool& success)
{
    ...
}
```

But I'd rather keep the pattern of my API as well as being able to do it via a single line in the if() statement if possible.

Perhaps something like:

```
bool get_front(int&& int_rvalue)
{
    ...
    int_rvalue = example_q.front();
    ...
    return true_or_false;
}


void calling_func()
{
    ...
    if(get_front(int& magical_ref))
    {
       ... //use magical_ref here?
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `int& get_front()
{
    return example_q.front();
}`?  Out parameters are generally considered a bad idea.

Comment: No, but you can pass a reference to a pointer and modify the pointer to point to your data. Better still, return a tuple with a reference and whatever else you need to return: `std::tuple<int&, bool> get_front()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Other than in its initialiser, a reference behaves like the thing it refers to. By passing it as a function argument, you "hide" the initialiser from the part that wants to do the assignment. So, the function has no access to the referencey behaviour of the thing.

You will have to use pointers if you want to do that:

```
void get_front(int*& int_ptr)
{
    int_ptr = &example_q.front(); 
}

int* ptr = nullptr;
get_front(ptr);

// optional:
int& ref = *ptr;
```

*(Ew!)*

Option B was fine.

Answer (score 4):

This code is invalid C++:

```
if(get_front(int& magical_ref))
```

You cannot declare a new variable as you're passing it to a function. And because a reference variable must be declared and initialized at the same time, it wouldn't be possible to have a reference be initialized by passing it to a function.

You *could* however, do this:

```
if(int &magical_ref = get_front()) {
```

But note that you'd be checking whether `magical_ref` is 0 or not, which is different from the condition you have in your example.

If your logic is as simple as comparing the `int`, you could do:

```
if (int& magical_ref = get_front(); magical_ref == 42)
```

Comment: Here's the fun bit, I'm doing a trivial example in the question but the actual usecase is getting a reference of an std::unique_ptr from a queue that is not guaranteed to be full XD.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `std::tuple<int&, /* status condition */>` and check the status. For example:

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, bool> get_front() {
    static int example = 0;
    return {example, false};
}

...

// C++17's structured bindings + if statement with initializer
if (auto [ref, success] = get_front(); success) {
    ref = 42;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/LfaOr3)

Comment: That would be my recommended solution for multiple returns, except I've the self imposed limit of C++11 at the moment due to backwards compatibility concerns